# Writeline to textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Stupid question here, but here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = CType(dgrGrid.DataSource, DataTable).Copy
    Dim drs() As DataRow = dt.Select("CustomerID = 222")
    For Each row As DataRow In drs
        For Each item As Object In row.ItemArray
            Debug.WriteLine("{0}", item)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I can see in the debug window all my values.

Now if I need to spit out this value to a textbox, I am not sure how to do it.

The goal is to keep using `itemArray` to get the value.

Comment: you want to put all the values into one textbox???

Comment: I suppose you want to do that just for learning or debugging purpose.

Comment: mainly trying to see what I can do with ItemArray. The focus is on itemArray

Comment: You can do something like what I did in the answer.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try

Comment: filtering the `DataGridView` results might be easier for debugging : `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CustomerID = 222"` and then `.RowFilter = ""` when done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Dim rows = dt.Select() ' Or select using a criteria like you did
Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, _
    rows.Select(Function(r) String.Join(",", r.ItemArray)))
```

The `TextBox1` should be `MultiLine` to show `Environment.NewLine`.

Also if you are looking for something like `AppendLine`, use:

```
Me.TextBox1.AppendText("something" & Environment.NewLine)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Reza's answer, and if you're lazy like me and don't want to write `Environment.NewLine` everywhere, you can create an extension method for adding new lines:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub AppendLine(ByVal TargetTextBox As TextBox, ByVal Text As String)
        TargetTextBox.AppendText(Text & Environment.NewLine)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Usage:

```
For Each item As Object In row.ItemArray
    TextBox1.AppendLine(item.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: Just rename the extension method to `WriteLine` if you prefer it to be called that instead. :)

Comment: I was going to add the extension method to the answer because of title of the question, but reading this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810596/writeline-to-textbox/40810768#comment68842593_40810596) changed my mind. But the question title needs such answer :)

Comment: Doesn't seem lazy to me :] The laziest Is probably the usual `TextBox1.Text &= item & vbCrLf`, but it will not scroll to the last line like `.AppendLine` does. Something that I found interesting from the `.AppendLine` reference source is that it selects the end of text and replaces the selection. `Textbox.Paste(String)` uses the same internal method to replaces the selection, but also clears the undo buffer.